# How do I make ArchiPack windows transparent?

Tags: materials, windows, archipack-add-on

When watching multiple YouTube videos, when they bring in an object with a window from Archipack it's automatically transparent. When I do it doesn't seem to have a material. I have downloaded the materials from Archipack and pointed it to the folder. I've confirmed that some objects do come in with their materials, such as staircases, etc. Does anyone have any idea's on what to try to get the materials to display in the viewport?

Comment: what blender version are u using? can u attach a sample file where u added an archimesh window?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using Eevee or Workbench as your Render Engine (Camera Icon). To see the realtime reflections from ArchiPack models, and the translucence of the Glass you'll have to switch it to Cycles under the Render Engine. The Device should be updated to be GPU to help with computing Power.